# Calculate different discount levels in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have to create a price list with 3 different discount levels called eg. E1, E2, E3.
E1 = 10%, E2 = 20% and E3 =30% discount.

How do I write a formula to tell Excel if the item falls in class E1 it must apply a 10% discount, if class E2, it must apply 20% discount, etc?

My price list layout must look similar to this:

```
Model   Descr        ListPrice  Class    Net Price      
Apple1  StarKing     R 50.00    E1       R 45.00        
Grape1  Dauphine     R 20.00    E2       R 16.00        
Pear1   Rosmarie     R 50.00    E3       R 35.00
```

Comment: I'm not against this question, but I'm curious. Does it actually belong here? It's not about hard- or soft-ware.

Comment: @Xavierjazz we have a pretty large database of excel questions, vba and worksheet functions. For this question, in particular, the user did not show what attempts have been made and is instead asking someone to solve the problem rather than clarify where they went wrong in what they attempted. It's on-topic, but not a good question.

Answer (score 1):

A more scalable solution would be to have a table of discounts, such as:

```
   A   B  
1  E1  0.1
2  E2  0.2
3  E3  0.3
```

And then your original table:

```
   D       E            F          G        H
1  Model   Descr        ListPrice  Class    Net Price      
2  Apple1  StarKing     R 50.00    E1       =(1-VLOOKUP(G2,$A$1:$B$3,2))*F2
3  Grape1  Dauphine     R 20.00    E2       =(1-VLOOKUP(G3,$A$1:$B$3,2))*F3
4  Pear1   Rosmarie     R 50.00    E3       =(1-VLOOKUP(G4,$A$1:$B$3,2))*F4
```

Comment: thank you for this suggestion as well, I have another price list where this formula will be 100% suitable. thanks again for all the help :)

Comment: @Grethe  , Please accept the answer by ticking it, this will mark the question solved. For the details see: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `ListPrice` is column `C` and `Class` is column `D`, in `E2` you'd have the formula:

```
=IF(D2="E1",C2*10%,IF(D2="E2",C2*20%,IF(D2="E3",C2*30%,C2)))
```

That formula applies a discount if the Class is one of those you specified, otherwise no discount is applied. If you want a "blank" cell if the class is not one of those you specified, use 0 or an empty string:

```
=IF(D2="E1",C2*10%,IF(D2="E2",C2*20%,IF(D2="E3",C2*30%,"")))
=IF(D2="E1",C2*10%,IF(D2="E2",C2*20%,IF(D2="E3",C2*30%,0)))
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much - works like a bomb!

Comment: Glad I could help. If this answer solved your problem, please [*accept*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.